# C++ Text-based Game - "Map" Implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to create a text-based adventure game.  I'm thinking I want the map to be represented by different nodes where each node corresponds to a distinct location and has node pointer variables (left, forward, and right) that should point to another node in the respective direction.  I tried to implement it as a linked list, but with this data structure, I could only have each node point to one other node.  I want each node to point to three other nodes.  Which data structure could I use to implement this or is this even possible?

Comment: modify your data structure to have four Node pointers pointing to left, right, forward and next .

Comment: You don't need a name to implement a data structure. Just make each Node point to three other Nodes. Or maybe four, if you ever want your character to be able to go back.

Comment: If each node has three pointers, how would I add each one to the list? The map needs to be the same every time I generate it.

Comment: @user2280464 I've touched on this in my answer

Answer (score 2):

A linked datastructure would do a good job of doing what you want:

example:

```
class location
{
    std::string loc_name;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,location*>> connections;
    std::string description;
public:
    bool add_link(location* loc, std::string dicription_to, std::string dicription_from);
    //other parameters + functions to manage class
}
```

This would allow you to create locations such as:

```
location* loc = new location("graveyard");
loc->description = "A spooky graveyard on a hill, a cool mist floats amongst the gravestones and monuments";
loc->add_link(crypt /*previously defined*/, 
              "An imposing mausoleum with an open door, steps inside lead down into darkness", 
              "Moonlight filters down from the top of some steps, a way out?");
loc.add_link(spooky_house /*previously defined*/, 
              "The North gate of the graveyard", 
              "The entrance to the house's spooky graveyard");
```

I'd reccommend creating a map file you could read in though. Possibly using a template like this:

locations file:

```
/*locations, format = "name; description"*/
Spooky House; house_description
Crypt;        crypt_description
Graveyard;    A spooky graveyard on a hill, a cool mist floats amongst the gravestones and monuments
```

links file:

```
/*links, format = "index # (from); index # (to); description (from->to); description (to->from)"*/
3;2;An imposing mausoleum with an open door, steps inside lead down into darkness; Moonlight filters down from the top of some steps, a way out?
3;1;The North gate of the graveyard;The entrance to the house's spooky graveyard;
```

Loading the map would be as simple as reading in all the locations and pushing them into a vector for storage, then adding the links in to connect them.

Comment: When I try to build the program, I get an error: 'bool location::add_link(location*)' is private

Comment: members of a class are private by default, you need to add a `public:` lable to make them accessable (updated answer to show one for `add_link` function)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a custom linked datastructure with linked positions on the map like this:

```
struct Map_Node{
    Map_Node *left;
    Map_Node *right;
    Map_Node *forward;
    /* other needed field*/
};
```

Then, you need to do the memory management on your own. For example by using smart pointers.

```
std::shared_ptr<Map_Node> entry{ new MapNode };
std::shared_ptr<Map_Node> hallway{ new MapNode };
entry->forward = &*hallway;
//and so on
```

An easier but less efficient for getting the next file would be a std::map. If each position
has its unique ID, e.g. a string, you could store the IDs of the neighboring fields and move freely on the map by using the ID.

```
struct Map_Node{
    std::string name;
    std::string left;
    std::string right;
    std::string forward;
    /* other needed field*/
};

std::map<std::string, Map_Node> map;
Map_Node entry;
entry.name = "entry";
map[entry.name] = entry; 

Map_Node hallway;
hallway.name = "hallway";
map[hallway.name] = hallway; 

//links between:
map["entry"].forward = "hallway";
```

Comment: And I was pretty much just writing this (though I used N,S,E,W)

Comment: @Baldrickk For simple direction like N,S,E,W one could think about using a simple  two-dimentional datestructure (vector, array or whatever).

Comment: Well, I meant I used N,S,E,W instead of left, right...  Using a vector would be nice though, for example: you may decide to have multiple floors, in which case you could have extra links between nodes (up and down).  You'd probably want to store a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, node*>>` in that case, so you could name each connection.

Comment: when implementing the std::map, I get an error "Field 'forward' could not be resolved" after  map["entry"].forward = "hallway";

Comment: @user2280464 is there a public field `forward` in the type returned by the map? Here is the example compiling and running: http://ideone.com/lbIbsG